# google api access token null for local java client with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I created a service account to use Google chat (not bot) from a local java client. My objective is to migrate flowdock data to Google chat.

I tried different means to get access token using service account and looked at several docs and forums...

Certificate is loaded with all certificate informations. But access token stays null.

```
public class ChatScopes {
static final String CHAT_SPACES = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces";
static final String CLOUD_AUTH = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
static final String CHAT_MESSAGES = "https://www.googleapis.com/chat.messages.create";
static final String CHAT_SPACES_2 = "https://www.googleapis.com/chat.spaces.create";
static final List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(
        ChatScopes.CLOUD_AUTH, 
        ChatScopes.CHAT_SPACES,
        ChatScopes.CHAT_SPACES_2, 
        ChatScopes.CHAT_MESSAGES);
```

}
...

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(AuthenticationService.class.getResourceAsStream(CERT_FILE))
            .createScoped(ChatScopes.scopes);
```

1.a

```
AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken(); // IOException: Error parsing token refresh response. Expected value access_token not found.
```

1.b

```
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken(); // token is null
```

### Update with example [Service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts)##

```
GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleCredential
            .fromStream(AuthenticationService.class.getResourceAsStream(CERT_FILE_2))
            .createScoped(Collections.singleton(ChatScopes.CHAT_SPACES));

return new HangoutsChat.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credentials )
            .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
            .build();
            .build();
```

**response** when requesting using hangoutsChat because access token stays null (with or without calling refresh and/or getAccessToken)
GET https: //chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces

```
{
"code": 401,
"details": [
    {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING"
    }
],
"errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header",
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "reason": "required"
    }
],
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
```

}

Comment: Have you tested the example from the documentation on OAuth 2.0 Java [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts)?

Comment: yes this one gives me 401 json response because access token stays null (with or without calling refresh and/or getAccessToken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we need some clean code crafting here. The error came in fact from wrong scopes declaration. Adding chat bot (why as I don't need bot ?) made me advance.

**Scopes**

```
public class ChatScopes {
static final String CLOUD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
static final String CHAT_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat";
static final String CHAT_BOT_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot";
static final List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(
    CLOUD_SCOPE,
    CHAT_SCOPE,
    CHAT_BOT_SCOPE);
```